# Unrecognized selector sent to instance (typecast issue?)

Tags: xcode

I'm creating a Connect Four-type game in Xcode for a class project and am getting stuck on a helper function. I have a button above each column of the "game board" to drop the piece into the game. The board is essentially a 7x6 grid of UIImageView (whether or not this is the most practical I don't really care about, it's about as much as we have been taught in this class).

My helper function:
(declared in .h:
    NSString* imgString;
    UIImageView* prevImg;
    UIImageView* curImg;
)

```
-(void) dropToken:(int) column
{
    [ self checkTurn ];
    for(int i=1; i<6; i++)
    {
        imgString = [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"img%d%d", i, column ];
        curImg = (UIImageView*) imgString;
        curImg.image = [ UIImage imageNamed: @"redpiece.png" ];
        if(i != 6)
        {
            prevImg = curImg;
            imgString = [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"img%d%d", i+1, column ];
            curImg = (UIImageView*) imgString;
            if(curImg.image == nil)
            {
                prevImg.image = nil;
                curImg.image = curToken;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it's supposed to take in the column as a parameter, and then go to the appropriate UIImageView, and set the image there to the current players token.

However I'm getting:

> -[__NSCFString setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b09ee0

on the line: curImg.image = [ UIImage imageNamed: @"redpiece.png" ];

is there an issue with my typecast? Or am I overlooking some easily fixed issue?

Comment: What are you expecting `curImg = (UIImageView*) imgString` to do? I can't figure out why you thought that was appropriate. `imgString` is an `NSString`. Casting it doesn't change what it is. It just changes what the compiler *thinks* it is. So basically, you're lying to the compiler, and it blows up in your face.

Comment: Do you have `UIImageView`s called `img11`, `img12`, `img21`, etc by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin has a good point in his comment, this line will never work:

```
curImg = (UIImageView*) imgString;
```

I think you want to do something more like this:

```
imgString = [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"img%d%d", i, column ];
        UIImageView* imgView = [UIImageView initWithImage:[ UIImage imageNamed: @"redpiece.png" ]];
```

This is code I've written in this page, so it might not even compile but the idea is you need to create the UIImageView with a UIImage with string you created.

Comment: Thank you - initWithImage is exactly what I was looking for. We've hardly been taught any C/C++ (let alone the version iphone programming uses). T